# ¿Por que se cambian mis dos variables?

Tags: nodejs

Quiero enmascarar un numero pero al realizarlo lo quiero meter en una variable, mi problema es que trato de separar en dos variables diferentes para que en una se realice el cambio y la otra quede intacto pero se cambia en los dos:

```
let body = req.body;

     let json = req.body;

     let card = req.body.PagoElectronico.PAN
     if (card != '') {
         let cardHide = cardHide(card)

         json.PagoElectronico.PAN = cardHide;
         console.log("json111111", json);
     }
     console.log("json1212121", body);
```

con esta funcion hago el cambio el cual se hace correctamente solo que lo hace en las dos variables tanto json como body y solo necesito que se cambie en json y no en body.

```
function cardHide(card) {
 let hideNum = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
   if (i < card.length - 4) {
     hideNum.push("*");
   } else {
     hideNum.push(card[i]);
   }
 }

 return hideNum.join("");
}
```

esos console log me imprimen el numero enmascarado en los dos. llamo enmascarar a ocultar los digitos y mostrar solo asteriscos *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate en estas declaraciones:

```
let body = req.body;
let json = req.body;
```

En la memoria existe un objeto y su referencia está guardada en `req.body`, lo que hacen las asignaciones anteriores es guardar esa referencia en una variable llamada `body` y en otra llamada `json`, no se crean nuevas copias del objeto original, siempre se modifica el mismo.

Si quieres una copia tienes que clonarlo, por ejemplo:

```
let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))
```

Primero se convierte el objeto original en una cadena y luego esa cadena se convierte a un objeto nuevo. Ahora los cambios en `json` no se reflejarán en `body`.